# Named Credentials of type custom for authorization

Tags: namedcredentials

We have the following logic implemented to get the access Token and we want this to be implemented using the Named credentials

```
Http http = new Http();

HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();

req.setEndpoint(String.format(Url,CustomSetting.Client_Id__c));

req.setMethod('POST');

req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');

req.setHeader('Authorization','Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(CustomSetting.Client_Id__c + ':' + CustomSetting.Client_Secret__c)));

req.setHeader('Connection','keep-alive');

req.setHeader('Content-Length', '0');

req.setTimeout(Integer.valueOf(customSetting.Timeout__c * 1000));

HttpResponse response = http.send(req);

if(response.getStatusCode() == 201) {

 Map<String, Object> resultMap = (Map<String, Object>) 
 JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());

 authToken = 'Bearer ' + (String)resultMap.get('accessToken'); 
           
}
```

Followed the link given in this idea and setup the Named Credentials
Another question is passing the  client Id and client Secret as two parameters in the principals and how to access them in apex is what I want to know?

https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdYlxUAF/name-credentials-to-support-client-id-authentication

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the `Authorization` header you leave that to the named credential framework to add, signalled by the special `callout` URL scheme:

```
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        String url = String.format(
            'callout:{0}{1}',
            new Object[] {credentialName, relativeUrl}
        );
        req.setEndpoint(url);
```

See e.g. [Named Credentials as Callout Endpoints](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials.htm) for more explanation.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I figured out the issue is with the setup of the Custom Named Credentials where the Sequence to set as two Named Principals.

Answer (score 0):

When preparing the External Credentials we can give the `Client ID` and `Client Secret` appended as follows in the Custom Headers.

```
 Authorization {!'Basic ' & BASE64ENCODE(BLOB($Credential.ExtCred.ClientId & ':' & $Credential.ExtCred.ClientSecret))}
```

Then named credentials will take care of it no need to pass anything externally.

Comment: Starting with Winter '24, [`client_credentials` is available out of the box](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_security_named_credentials_clientcredentials.htm&release=246&type=5) and the formula is not needed.